# AWS SageMaker Pipeline Model endpoint deployment failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-sagemaker

I want to deploy a Sagemaker Pipeline Model having 2 containers. I am referring to this: Link: https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/pipeline.html.

The first container will contain image pre-processing code and second container will contain the model inference code.
I have updated the docker files of both the containers to have the following line:

```
# Set a docker label to enable container to use SAGEMAKER_BIND_TO_PORT environment variable if present
LABEL com.amazonaws.sagemaker.capabilities.accept-bind-to-port=true
```

I have tested the 2 containers separately by deploying the normal endpoints with single container. Both the endpoints are getting deployed and working as intended.
But when I try to deploy the pipeline model, the endpoint is not getting deployed and giving me following error:

```
UnexpectedStatusException: Error hosting endpoint sagemaker-inference-pipeline-endpoint: Failed.
Reason:  The container-1,container-2 for production variant AllTraffic did not pass the ping health check. 
Please check CloudWatch logs for this endpoint..
```

I have checked the cloudwatch logs for both the containers and there is no error shown related to "health check" failure.
Please have a look at the cloudwatch log of 1 container (2nd one is also same):

```
Starting the inference server with 2 workers.
[2022-11-20 14:50:44 +0000] [15] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-11-20 14:50:44 +0000] [15] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock (15)
[2022-11-20 14:50:44 +0000] [15] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-11-20 14:50:44 +0000] [18] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18
[2022-11-20 14:50:44 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19
```

Please note: For testing purpose, now I have also updated my code which does the following thing:

- Always returning health-check as True (Status 200)
- every input-output content type is: "text/plain"

---

Please guide me on what I am be missing unknowingly or making a mistake somewhere. Thanks a lot in advance.

Summary of things I have tried:

1. Tested both the containers separately as endpoint deployments. Both the containers got deployed as endpoints
2. I have read the documentation part and got to know that we need tell docker regarding port-binding. Added the below line in the dockerfile:

```
# Set a docker label to enable container to use SAGEMAKER_BIND_TO_PORT environment variable if present
LABEL com.amazonaws.sagemaker.capabilities.accept-bind-to-port=true
```

3. Updated code in both the containers respective code files to always return health-check as pass (Status: 200)
4. Every input-output content-type updated to: "text/plain" (so that there is no anomaly even in inter-container communication)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I was able to resolve this issue

---

The actual problem is that the endpoint is not able to **ping** the container. It is because, when there are multiple containers, every container is using some dynamic port for communication and endpoint needs to know which port every container is using. Hence, we need to write a custom code to replace the port value[8080] in nginx.conf file from the value which is inside the ['SAGEMAKER_BIND_TO_PORT'] environment variable.

The code to do the above thing is referenced from this sagemker example: https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/contrib/inference_pipeline_custom_containers/containers

In the serve file, use the below **start_server()** function:

```
def start_server():
    print('Starting the inference server with {} workers.'.format(model_server_workers))

    # link the log streams to stdout/err so they will be logged to the container logs
    subprocess.check_call(['ln', '-sf', '/dev/stdout', '/var/log/nginx/access.log'])
    subprocess.check_call(['ln', '-sf', '/dev/stderr', '/var/log/nginx/error.log'])
    
    port = os.environ.get("SAGEMAKER_BIND_TO_PORT", 8080)
    print("using port: ", port)
    with open("nginx.conf.template") as nginx_template:
        template = Template(nginx_template.read())    
    nginx_conf = open("/opt/program/nginx.conf", "w")
    nginx_conf.write(template.substitute(port=port))
    nginx_conf.close()

    nginx = subprocess.Popen(['nginx', '-c', '/opt/program/nginx.conf'])
    gunicorn = subprocess.Popen(['gunicorn',
                                 '--timeout', str(model_server_timeout),
                                 '-k', 'sync',
                                 '-b', 'unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock',
                                 '-w', str(model_server_workers),
                                 'wsgi:app'])

    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, lambda a, b: sigterm_handler(nginx.pid, gunicorn.pid))

    # If either subprocess exits, so do we.
    pids = set([nginx.pid, gunicorn.pid])
    while True:
        pid, _ = os.wait()
        if pid in pids:
            break

    sigterm_handler(nginx.pid, gunicorn.pid)
    print('Inference server exiting')
```

Instead of nginx.conf use nginx.conf.template which will in-turn create the nginx.conf file with proper port:

```
worker_processes 1;
daemon off; # Prevent forking


pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
  # defaults
}

http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;
  
  upstream gunicorn {
    server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock;
  }

  server {
    listen $port deferred;
    client_max_body_size 5m;

    keepalive_timeout 5;
    proxy_read_timeout 1200s;

    location ~ ^/(ping|invocations) {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $$http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://gunicorn;
    }

    location / {
      return 404 "{}";
    }
  }
}
```